# how to fix XSS Reflected in java

Tags: xss, java

I got fortify report which shows XSS Reflected defect from the below 2nd line.

> String name = request.getParameter("name");
>
> response.getWriter().write("Name: " + name);

Recommendation given: All user input displayed to web clients should HTML encoded and validated.
This is java code and I am not sure about how to fix this.

Answer (score 10):

A simple way, you can just use the OWASP Enterprise Security API (Java Edition) :

```
 String safe = ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML( request.getParameter( "input" ) );
```

See those link:

[OWASP Enterprise Security API (Java Edition) Documentation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

[OWASP Enterprise Security API (Java Edition) Code Example](https://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/codecs/HTMLEntityCodec.java)

Comment: dead link......

Comment: cheatsheet link, will edit when possible: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html