# How to fix Checkmarx vulnerability for Checkmarx scan 'reflected XSS all clients'?

Tags: java, xss, checkmarx

Checkmarx scanner scans for "Reflected XSS all clients".
How to resolve this in JAVA REST API?

Locally ran the scan for REST API service.

Comment: see if this may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193750/how-to-fix-xss-reflected-in-java. Your question is not very specific, so can't help you much.

Comment: Hello Shruti Patil and welcome to stack overflow. It is impossible to answer your question without seeing at least parts of the code you are trying to correct. If you want a general answer, you may look for it here: https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md

Answer (score 1):

Use a good [encoder](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project) for all the data you push to the client side.